# Xamarin WatchOS build error on VS for Mac 2019

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac, watchos, visual-studio-2019

On Visual studio for mac 2019, the default watchOS breaks on build with the error below.
The phone-app project only builds successfully before adding the WatchOS project from VS project template.

Help please.

> ERROR
>   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(4,4):
>   Error MSB4094:
>   "/Users/devpc/Projects/SampleWatchApp/Watch/Watch.WatchOSExtension/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/WatchWatchOSExtension.appex;/Users/devpc/Projects/SampleWatchApp/Watch/Watch.WatchOSExtension/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/WatchWatchOSExtension.appex"
>   is an invalid value for the "Source" parameter of the "Ditto" task.
>   Multiple items cannot be passed into a parameter of type
>   "Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem". (MSB4094) (Watch.WatchOSApp)

Comment: Have you tried running one of the watch samples https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/tree/master/watchOS/WatchConnectivity to see if it is a project config error?

Comment: Can you try delete bin and obj folder, then rebuild your project to check if it works.

Comment: Deleting the folders has not effect. You should know also that i did not edit the default code from the template. I just created and built and ...error

Comment: @IainSmith the WatchConnectivity Sample worked. But why will the default project from VS for mac 2019 template not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realized that VS for mac 2019 for some reason adds double references for the Watch-Extension project.

Removing one reference solves the problem.

[image]